# How to hide contents of <i class="abc">content</i> (font awesome)

Tags: html, css, tags, hide

I want to hide **search** from

```
<i class="far fa-search">search</i>
```

using css. Before we were using material icons

```
<i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>*
```

and there it was hidden (**mode_edit**)

I already tried looking around, but couldn't figure a way out using only css.

Comment: @Gosi That would hide the entire icon. OP wants to hide only the text, keeping the icon intact.

Comment: OP consult their docs on how to do this correctly, so that your icon also remains accessible. https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/accessibility#web-fonts-semantic

Essentially, wrap the text in a span tag and hide the span.

Comment: lol, that means just remove the text? as in like, backspace the text within ?

Comment: I'm assuming he means to hide text but to keep for screen readers, or when the icon font fails to load or something.

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete 'search' from inside the tags. 
so it will look like this:

`<i class="far fa-search"></i>`

if you wanted to keep the text for screen readers you could do this:

`<i class="far fa-search"><span class="hidden">Search</span></i>`

css file should have:

`.hidden{display:none;}`

Comment: All else being equal, `class="hidden"`won't hide anything.

Comment: Youre right, i assumed OP would have a good enough understanding off CSS to implement the class, Ive updated my answer in case they dont

Comment: Re edit: The usual goal of having an icon with associated hidden text is to provide content that is friendly to screen reader and search engine software. Using `display: none` will hide the text from screen readers and risk looking like keyword stuffing to search engines.